# WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_CLIENT Socket write error: 111

Tags: in-memory-database, aerospike

im getting error

```
$ aql
2015-10-10 15:48:10 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_CLIENT Socket write error: 111
Error -1: Failed to seed cluster
```

can anyone help me out of this.............!

Comment: Is Aerospike running? Is it on the local machine? If not you will need to call AQL with the -h option.

Comment: First check that Aerospike is running: `/etc/init.d/aerospike status`

Answer (score 3):

Is Aerospike running on the same host where you did run aql?

If it is, is it listening on the local 127.0.0.1 interface and on the default port (3000)? (feel free to share your configuration).

If it is not, then make sure to specify the host and port when running aql using the -h and -p options: `aql -h <ip> -p <port>`

Answer (score 0):

The port is not getting freed up even after exiting the vagrant.

Restarting the system freed all the ports and thus the service got up.